# How to declare noexcept if only a member function of an attribute is noexcept?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, clang, noexcept

```
#include <vector>
class A
{
    std::vector<int> vec;

    void swap( A & other) noexcept(noexcept(vec.swap(other.vec)))
    {
        vec.swap(other.vec);
    }

};

int main()
{
}
```

This code compiles under clang(3.4) but not under gcc (4.7.1). Anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

gcc error message is :

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class A’
error: forward declaration of ‘class A’
```

Comment: Error message, please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a work around, you may use (which works for gcc 4.7.1, gcc 4.8.1 and clang 3.4):

```
void swap(A& other) noexcept(noexcept(std::declval<decltype(A::vec)&>().swap(std::declval<decltype(A::vec)&>())))
```

or

```
void swap(A& other) noexcept(noexcept(vec.swap(vec)))
```

I think the problem is `other.vec`...