# Can we refer to member variables in a noexcept specification?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, c++17, noexcept

Please consider the following code snippet:

```
template<class Tuple>
class vector
{
public:
    typename Tuple::size_type size() const noexcept(noexcept(m_elements.size())) {
        return m_elements.size();
    }

private:
    Tuple m_elements;
};

class tuple
{
public:
    using size_type = std::size_t;

    size_type size() const { return 0; }
    size_type size() noexcept { return 0; }
};    

int main()
{
    vector<tuple> x;
    static_assert(noexcept(x.size()), "x.size() might throw");

    return 0;
}
```

Is the use of the member variable `m_elements` inside the `noexcept` specifier legal? [GCC 5.2 (C++17) yields the compiler error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=7d2a18fa7e70f9e0) *`m_elements` was not declared in this scope*. while [clang 3.6 (C++17) compiles without any error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=13b213cf8de3b9b1).

Both compilers yield no error if I use `noexcept(std::declval<Tuple const&>().size())` instead. However, as you can see, I've created a simple example class `tuple` where it's crucial whether or not `Tuple` has qualified overloads of `size`.

From my point of view, it's more intuitive to write `noexcept(m_elements.size())` cause it's exactly the call in the function body and it takes into account that the `size` method of `vector` is `const` qualified (which makes `m_elements` a const object in the scope of the function).

So, what's the legal usage? If both are equivalent, which should I use? Should I use `noexcept` qualifiers at all in this scenario? The problem is that whether or not the `vector` functions will throw depends in all most every case on `Tuple`.

Comment: I would like to note that there [has been a question concerning the use of member variables inside a `noexcept` specification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27241938/noexcept-depending-on-method-of-member) here on the board, but please note that this question is related to C++11 and a compiler error generated by (some unknown version of) clang.

Answer (score 8):

Clang is correct here, this is gcc bug [52869](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52869). According to [[basic.scope.class]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.class#1), emphasis mine:

> The potential scope of a name declared in a class consists not only of the declarative region following the
>   name’s point of declaration, but also of all function bodies, default arguments, **exception-specifications**, and *brace-or-equal-initializers* of non-static data members in that class (including such things in nested
>   classes).

The scope of `m_elements` includes the *noexcept-specification* for `size()`.

Comment: @JonathanWakely 52869 is supposed to have been fixed in trunk ([r266224](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc?view=revision&revision=266224)) but gcc still rejects OP's snippet (`__VERSION__` == `"9.0.0 20181204 (experimental)"`)

Comment: @Oktalist, the bug doesn't actually say it's fixed (status is still NEW). I've added a new comment with a reduced example that still fails.