# noexcept specifier for _Not_fn function call operator

Tags: c++, c++17, libstdc++

In this question I consider the libstdc++ [implementation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/libstdc++/api/a00071_source.html#l00842) of the `_Not_fn` call wrapper.

It defines four overloads of function call operator as follows:

> ```
>  #define _GLIBCXX_NOT_FN_CALL_OP( _QUALS )                          \
>        template<typename... _Args>                                  \
>     decltype(_S_not<__inv_res_t<_Fn _QUALS, _Args...>>())           \
>     operator()(_Args&&... __args) _QUALS                            \
>     noexcept(noexcept(_S_not<__inv_res_t<_Fn _QUALS, _Args...>>())) \
>     {                                                               \
>       return !std::__invoke(std::forward< _Fn _QUALS >(_M_fn),      \
>                             std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);        \
>     }
>        _GLIBCXX_NOT_FN_CALL_OP( & )
>        _GLIBCXX_NOT_FN_CALL_OP( const & )
>        _GLIBCXX_NOT_FN_CALL_OP( && )
>        _GLIBCXX_NOT_FN_CALL_OP( const && )
>  #undef _GLIBCXX_NOT_FN_CALL
> ```

It is easy to see, that noexcept specification is set as:

> ```
> noexcept(noexcept(_S_not<__inv_res_t<_Fn _QUALS, _Args...>>()))
> ```

where `__inv_res_t` is an alias template:

> ```
> template<typename _Fn2, typename... _Args>
> using __inv_res_t = typename __invoke_result<_Fn2, _Args...>::type;
> ```

and `_S_not` is a static member function template:

> ```
> template<typename _Tp>
> static decltype(!std::declval<_Tp>())
> _S_not() noexcept(noexcept(!std::declval<_Tp>()));
> ```

Now, following the logic behind noexcept specification I conclude, that:

1. Function call operator conceptually has the same noexcept specification as `_S_not<__inv_res_t<_Fn _QUALS, _Args...>>`.
2. `_S_not<__inv_res_t<_Fn _QUALS, _Args...>>` is marked as noexcept depending on whether a negation applied to the result of `std::__invoke(...)` is noexcept.

From my point of view, this noexcept specification doesn't cover the case when the callable object, wrapped into `not_fn`, may or may not throw itself while being invoked with a particular set of arguments passed to `not_fn` function call operator. In other words, **it is not checked if `std::__invoke(...)` itself inside a function call operator might throw or not**.

Do I miss something in this implementation?

The implementation from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/not_fn) has a bit simpler noexcept specification. However, this implementation doesn't work with the latest g++ due to a [known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35872045/can-we-refer-to-member-variables-in-a-noexcept-specification).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually no requirement that `not_fn` propagate `noexcept`. It is specified in [[func.not_fn]](http://eel.is/c++draft/func.not_fn), each of the four call operators just looks something like:

> ```
> template<class... Args>
>   auto operator()(Args&&...) const&
>     -> decltype(!declval<invoke_result_t<const FD&, Args...>>());
> ```

No `noexcept`. That said, [P0356](https://wg21.link/p0356) proposes to add it and the current `noexcept` specifier makes no sense and could cause harm by being wrong, so filed [87538](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87538).

---

Update: this has been fixed for 7.4, 8.3 and 9.1.

Comment: Thanks, Barry! Somehow, I overlooked the fact that the standard doesn't impose a noexcept restriction on not_fn function call operator. Current noexcept specifier doesn't make much sense for me either, so it is great to have a bug being opened!